# How can I capture function arguments as strings in R?

Tags: r, tidyeval

I want to capture the incoming arguments that I'm passing to a function.  How can I do this?  The function below isn't quite what I want.  The output I want is `"Using mtcars and am"`.  I was under the impression `rlang` could help with this, but I haven't been able to find a function to get the job done.

```
fx_capture<- function(fx_data, fx_var) {
  name_data <- quote(fx_data)
  name_var  <- quote(fx_var)
  paste("Using", name_data, "and", name_var)
}

fx_capture(mtcars, am)
> "Using fx_data and fx_var"
```

Comment: use `substitute(fx_data)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `deparse(substitute(arg))`

```
fx_capture<- function(fx_data, fx_var) {

     name_data <- deparse(substitute(fx_data))
     name_var <- deparse(substitute(fx_var))

     paste("Using", name_data, "and", name_var)
}

fx_capture(mtcars, am)
```

---

Or with `match.call`

```
fx_capture<- function(fx_data, fx_var) {

   paste0("Using ", do.call(paste, c(lapply(match.call()[-1], 
              as.character), sep = ' and ')))
  
  
}

fx_capture(mtcars, am)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `sys.call`

```
fx_capture<- function(fx_data, fx_var) {
  paste0("Using ", paste0(sys.call()[-1],collapse = " and "))
}
```

such that

```
> fx_capture(mtcars, am)
[1] "Using mtcars and am"
```